# Injection vs. Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class that reads some data form a file and then decodes that data.

I am trying to do the class as generic as possible, i.e. I want it to be able to decode any type of data.

The decoder itself is a generic interface.

I see 2 options:

1. Injection - Get the correct decoder as a parameter in the costructor

   MyReader(Decoder< T> decoder) {
       _decoder = decoder }
2. Inheritance - provide a virtual method that will return the correct decoder

   MyReader();
   virtual Decoder< T> GetDecoder()=0;

   Users of my class would simply need to inherit that class and implement only "GetDecoder".

The injection solution helps you reduce the number of classes used, while making the user know about the specific encoder.

The inheritance will require many classes, but encapsulates the usage of encoders.

What considered to be a better approach?

Comment: If MyReader is a type of Decoder, use inheritance. Otherwise, use composition (injection). 


Composition is usually considered a better practice because it enhances code reuse. It also enhances the single responsibility rule. Inheritance is useful in providing the same interface for access and extend current class's functionalities.

As a result, in your case, choice 1 seems better.

By the way, there are other options like "Policy". The best example would be the Allocator template argument in the std::vector definition.

Comment: @Hsi-HungShih can I use the Policy design pattern if the Decoder requires a special initialization? (constructor with arguments)?

Comment: Yes, you can use policies with custom initialization. Look at how predicates are passed for std::set etc.

Comment: @user844541 Usually policy template is stateless and only their static methods are used. If your policy template class has a constructor, you can construct it in your MyReader class and then use it, but using injection is more suitable because you can configure your dependency outside the MyReader class. If the parameters you use for decoder is compile time constant, you may be able to configure decoder using template argument, but I feel that would make the design less clear.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your "injection" approach would be storing the decoders via a common base class, and that you're considering alternatives more like:

```
MyReader(AbstractDecoder& decoder) : _decoder(decoder) { };

MyReader() { private: virtual Decoder<T>& GetDecoder() = 0; };
```

There are a few considerations:

- injection mean the client code has to take a more active role in creating and specifying the `Decoder`, and handling the errors that might happen during its lifetime, while with inheritance it's implicit in the choice of derived class and error handling can be more unified with `MyReader` errors;

  - with injection, there's a little bit more client awareness necessary in terms of understanding whether the `Decoder` is copied by the constructor (as you've done), or the caller needs to ensure a lifetime greater than the reader's, whether the same decoder can be passed to multiple `MyReader` constructors etc.. - all a bit more confusing and error prone
- injection means the `MyReader` API could potentially allow specification of another Decoder during the lifetime of the reader
- with inheritance, you end up with a lot more classes and the client code needs to be a little bit careful to avoid slicing, whereas with the injection it's `MyReader` itself that needs to be a little careful when storing/copying, but at least that's centralised and therrefore easier to get and keep right

CRTP is another alternative, with compile-time resolution and optimisations (dead code elimination, inlining etc).